# Use of double in codeblocks gives me int output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> using namespace std;
int main() 
{  
 double x=5.0,y=4.0,z;  
 z=x+y;     
 cout<<x<<endl<<y<<endl<<z;   
 return 0;
}
```

The above program gives me the following output:
5
4
9
When I have declared the variables to be double and even z as double why do I get the output as integer value(9)??

Comment: have you checked the precision? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Comment: This is the default output format and is how humans write numbers.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point numbers with no digits after the floating point are printed as integers by default.

To always show the floating point, use `setiosflags(ios::showpoint)`.

You can combine that with `fixed` and `setprecision(n)` I/O flags to limit how many digits to print after the floating point. For example:

```
double d = 5.0;
cout << setiosflags(ios::showpoint) << d << endl; // prints 5.00000
cout << setiosflags(ios::showpoint) << fixed << setprecision(1)
     << d << endl; // prints 5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`cout` is being helpful here: if the `double` value is a whole number, then it, by default, does not display a decimal separator followed by an arbitrary number of zeros.

If you *want* to display as many numbers as the precision that your particular `double` on your platform has, then use something on the lines of

```
cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10);
cout << fixed << x << endl;
```